# jquery validaiton plugin not working with file input

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have added class `required` to the file input and called the validation method but it does not work.

```
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="csvform" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="" method="POST" novalidate="novalidate"><input type="hidden" value="xxgzK81sfXh2IYsKG6zTwmKqRk87jXuJ3uQpb2J4" name="_token">

                    <input type="file" name="csv" id="csvform2" class="required" aria-required="true">

                    <input type="hidden" value="15" name="vendorID">
                    <br>
                    <button>Add CSV</button>

                    </form>

$( "#csvform" ).validate();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you must assign the rule using the `name` attribute of the relevant file `input` element.

For the `name="csv"` your jQuery should look like this:

```
 $("#csvform").validate({
        ignore: [],
        rules: {
            csv: { // <- name of input
                required: true,
                extension: "csv"
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hello, this works, however just having the `required` class and calling `validate()` on the form should work as it does in their example demo. I will wait a bit longer for that kind of answer, if not I will accept this since it does work. Thanks!

Comment: Great that this has worked. I had also some problems with only `.required` class, so I'm using this workaround that works for me perfectly. I would appreciate if you accept my answer later.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try [this](http://jqueryvalidation.org/accept-method/) with jQuery 'validate' Plugin.